# How to create an Iceberg table using Flink that is partitioned on STRUCT/ROW type's inner field?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-iceberg, data-lakehouse

I try to create the table like so:

```
Flink SQL> create table test (nested ROW(id STRING, name STRING)) partitioned by (nested.id);
```

But I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "." at line 1, column 78.
Was expecting one of:
    ")" ...
    "," ...
```

I've tried a bunch of options: `partitioned by ('nested.id')`, `partitioned by (nested.id)` but they all fail. There's no mention of this in the docs either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's close to no documentation on this, but I figured it out:

```
Schema schema = new Schema(
        optional(1, "id", Types.IntegerType.get()),
        optional(2, "name", Types.StringType.get()),
        optional(3, "address", Types.StructType.of(
                optional(4, "street", Types.StringType.get()),
                optional(5, "city", Types.StringType.get()),
                optional(6, "state", Types.StringType.get()),
                optional(7, "zip", Types.IntegerType.get())
        ))
);

Table table = new TableBuilder()
        .withSchema(schema)
        .withPartitionSpec(PartitionSpec.builderFor(schema)
                .identity("id")
                .bucket("address.city", 16)
                .build())
        .build();
```